# I am facing this problem "An error has occurred [object Progress Event]" while creating Realtime database in Firebase can anyone help me?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have refreshed again and again but it does not work. I also tried to log Out and then log in again but all in vain plz help.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Hey AD Rai, any update here? Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Steps to try:

1. Check if there are any relevant messages on the JavaScript console of your browser.
2. Disable all extensions in your browser and try again.
3. Try in an incognito window.
4. Try in a different browser.
5. Try on a different network.

If none of these work, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Change of network worked for me. Thanks you so much sir.